# how can I obtain a td with no value?

Tags: xpath

I have a table in which sometimes some records dont have a value

[image: this is what the chrome console shows me]

I am using these Xpath

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[not(td[string-length(normalize-space(text()))=0])]

//td[not(td[string-length(normalize-space(text()))=0])]
```

but it selects the whole table, how can I select only the td which are empty?

Thank you for all the help :)

Comment: "but it selects the whole table" what do you mean? Mentioned queries cannot select the whole table.

Comment: well, this one appears to be selecting all the td's in the table :/ even with text in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's keep things simple. If you want to select `td`s without text try:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[not(text())]
```

[Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctable%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EJanuary%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EFebruary%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%5Bnot(text())%5D&=%2F%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%5Bnot(text())%5D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)

Answer (score 0):

To complete, two alternatives to select empty `td` elements (the first one remove the useless parts of your XPath expression (`normalize-space()`, `text()`, and `td[]` inside the predicate) :

```
//td[string-length()=0]
//td[.=""]
```

The first XPath will look for td elements where the content length is equal to 0.
The second XPath will look for td elements which contain nothing.

But regarding your XPath tryouts, it seems you want to select `td` elements which are non-empty. If that's the case, just add a `not` inside the predicate :

```
//td[not(string-length()=0)]
//td[not(.="")]
```